# How do I create and use a spring boot testing utility class?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, spring-framework-beans

I want to create a utility class just for my tests that have some methods that all tests will use to reduce code duplication.

Where do I create this class and how do I import it in my tests?

**Errors**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'FooTest': Unsatisfied dependency
expressed through field 'myTestUtils'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 

No qualifying bean of type 'com.utils.MyTestUtils' available: expected 
at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**Files**

```
// src/test/com/example/utils/MyTestUtils.java

public class MyTestUtils {

 public String foo = "bar";

}
```

```
// src/test/com/example/services/FooTest.java

import com.example.utils.TestUtils;

@SpringBootTest

public class FooTest {
  
  // If I remove this decorator I get that this.testUtils is null
  @Autowired
  MyTestUtils myTestUtils

  @Test
  public void testFoo() throws Exception {}
  Asserthat(myTestUtils.foo).equals("bar")
}
```

**Update**

I solved the problem above with annotating the myTestUtils class with @Service

This works.

```
// src/test/com/example/utils/MyTestUtils.java

@Service
public class MyTestUtils {

 public String foo = "bar";

}
```

Comment: Unclear. You import it like any other Java class. Where to put it: that depends, but in your test source set seems like a good option?

Comment: With what exactly are you having problems? Why did your attempt(s) fail? Can you share your attempted solutions?

Comment: So you were trying to autowire a service component (Spring bean), not import a utility class. A utility class is a class with static-only methods.